# Matching and renaming columns on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
  ID Drive Volume Rep
  1   2     3      4
```

df2:

```
 ID 2Volume Drive_1 Reps
  1   2       3      4
```

I have matching the column names using a the table below

```
    df1    df2
   Drive   Drive_1
   Volume  2Volume
   Reps    Reps
```

Using the map in the table, how do I rename all the columns in df2 to be the same as the df1

I can use a simple df2 = df2.rename(columns={old:new}) to do this manually. But I want to general code that can work with different column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you don't want to do `df2 = df2.rename(columns={old:new})` manually, do you mean you want to pull `old` and `new` automatically from `table`? If so, you can do something like this:

```py
df2 = df2.rename(columns=dict(zip(table.df2, table.df1)))

#    ID  Drive  Volume  Reps
# 0   1      2       3     4
```

Or:

```py
df2 = df2.rename(columns=table.set_index('df2').df1)
```

Comment: I like this concept, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yes i understand that, but for some reason.. the column names aren't changing. Although there is no error

Comment: @tjjudge hmm maybe in your real there are spurious spaces either in the `df1`/`df2` column names or the `table` values (or are you saying even the example doesn't work for you)

Comment: Will post another question similar to the dataset I am currently working with. Please take a look at it if you can

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
```

If you wanna dynamically create a mapping dict of similar columns you can use `difflib`

```
import difflib
col1 = ['ID', 'Drive','Volume','Rep'] # df1.columns.values
col2 = [ 'ID', '2Volume', 'Drive_1', 'Reps']  # df2.columns.values
col_dict = {difflib.get_close_matches(col, col2)[0]:col for col in col1}
```

After, running the above code you'll have a dict like this -

```
{'ID': 'ID', 'Drive_1': 'Drive', '2Volume': 'Volume', 'Reps': 'Rep'}
```

The above dict can then be used to map columns

Comment: This would not know how to match the columns tho. Bare in mind, the columns can be in any order, and any name. First step is, mapping what column names from df1 are to be assigned to df2